# Como retornar a diferença de uma matriz em C# sem usar o LINQ?

Tags: c#, matriz

Tenho uma matriz A e B:

Metodo:

```
public static int[] RetornaDiferenca(int[] a, int[] b)
{...
}
```

Chamando o método:

```
RetornaDiferença(new int[] {1, 2, 2}, new int[] {2})
```

O resultado teria que ser: `new int[] {1}` pois todos os items de 'b' devem ser removidos de 'a'

Como fazer isso sem linq?

[Editado]
Outro detalhe:

```
RetornaDiferença(new int[] {1, 2, 2}, new int[] {1})
```

O retorno tem que ser:

```
int[] {2,2}
```

Comment: Existe algo que já tentou? Por que não pode usar LINQ? Essa descrição parece muito com exercício de um curso/faculdade.

Comment: Linq facilita muito, por isso pergunto como fazer sem utilizá-lo.
Ah, não é nada de faculdade - só praticando mesmo.

Comment: Deve ser restrição do exercício, mas não acho que esteja ampla de mais. De qualquer forma: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KSL1pU me lembrei dos tempos da faculdade

Comment: você precisa de 2 loop , 1 para percorrer B e para cada item de B percorrer A e remover os elementos idênticos de B em A. e retorna A simples assim.

Comment: e `RetornaDiferença(new int[] {1, 2, 2}, new int[] {2,3})` qual seria o retorno ?

Comment: Seria: new[] {1};